# Implementing A Debug Flag

Tags: clojure

Rather than go back through my libraries and adding a "debug" flag parameter, I thought that once a debug flag (0/1) was read on the command line of my application, a ref could be set once and then accessed by any function that needed to do something if the debug flag is set.

Is that a reasonable way to handle parameter-less debugging, or is my thinking too much like having a "forbidden" global variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global for this sort of thing is fine, although using a ref to store it isn't really appropriate because then you'd need to do all your logging in a transaction (ie. within a `(dosync)`).

Since you are unlikely to really care about race conditions on your 'logging-enabled' it doesn't need special protection. You'd mark this variable with *ear-muffs* to signal it has special meaning....

Something like this would be fine:

```
(def ^{:dynamic true} *debug-enabled* false)
(def ^{:dynamic true} *info-enabled* false)

(defn- log [level s]
  (println (apply str (cons (str "[" level "] ") s))))

(defn debug [ & s ]
  (when *debug-enabled*
    (log "DEBUG" s)))

(defn info [ & s ]
  (when *info-enabled*
    (log "INFO" s)))
```

Note that by defining the `*debug-enabled*` flag dynamic you can switch on debug for just *parts* of your code. In this example, imagine that all the functions used the `(debug)` functions mentioned above. You have `*debug-enabled*` set to false, but you'd like to turn it on just for `(my-problematic-func)`. You can re-bind the flag just for that call like this:

```
(myfunc a b c)
(my-other-func d e f)
(binding [*debug-enabled* true] ; switch on debug for my-problematic-func
   (my-problematic-func g h i))
```

Comment: As of Clojure 1.3, you can replace `^{:dynamic true}` with just `^:dynamic`. Also, whether you care about races or not is irrelevant here because this code _is_ thread-safe. Yes, it's not that easy to write unsafe code in Clojure!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to avoid repeating `(when *debug* ...)` all over your code. This is the primary target for a macro. Write a macro that does that check, so you can use it something like `(debug ...stuff...)`. OK, it's not much shorter, but it decouples your code from the specifics of checking for the debug flag. Better, it offers you a chance to write code which completely eliminates the runtime check of the debug flag and only does it at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of this flag is along the lines of application configuration, which is fine.  Go forth!